# I need more input tags, and my HTML/JavaScript combo isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My testing site is at http://grocerylistcalculator.site11.com/grocerycalculator.html# And the code, of course, can be found in view-source. The PHP script goes as follows:

```
<?php
    include 'header.html';
    $prices = $_POST['price'];
    $quantities = $_POST['numbe'];
    $total = 0;

    foreach ( $prices as $key => $p ) {
        $total += $p * $quantities[$key];
    }

    print "The total is ". $total;
    include 'footer.html';
?>
```

Note: PHP not written by me, provided on a different question. The code itself works, but I need to be able to add more input sections. The JavaScript is on the page.

Comment: What is the extension if your file??

Comment: Where is your HTML and JS code?

Comment: The JS throws: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null. So no, the code itself does not work :)

Answer (score 1):

So there's this (edited to create div, not input):

```
function addInput(divName){
    if (counter == limit)  {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    }
    else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "Price of entry " + (counter + 1) + "<input type='number' name='price[]' step='any'>  <br>Number of said entry: <input type='number' name='numbe[]' step='any'>";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
   }
}
```

but you call it without a parameter:

```
<p><a href="#" onClick="addInput()">Add a new input section</a><br/></p>
```

So first fix that. Then you can worry about the rest.

Also, make sure you're adding them **inside** the `form`

---

Update:
inside your form, before the submit button, create an empty div and pass that id to the `onlclick` function like so: `onClick="addInput('div_id_here')"`

Comment: Try `newdiv.value =` and remove the html markup from the string. Input elements don't have an innerHTML property and certainly can't have other input elements nested into them. (Well, not in IE at least) If it's supposed to be a div, `createElement('div')`.